# HTML rollover button image: how to do with Internet Explorer?

Tags: javascript, html

i've this simple piece of code that don't work in Internet Explorer, but do work in Chrome, Firefox etc.
It is a simple button image 'rollover' .

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <img src="p1.png" name="img1"  onMouseOver="document.images[0].src='p2.png'" onMouseOut="document.images[0].src='p1.png'" ></a>
</body>
</html>
```

What's wrong in IE 6,7,8 ?

Comment: I've tried with IE 6,7,8

Comment: why are you not using jquery, that will solve a lot of problems?

Comment: Works in IE 9: http://jsfiddle.net/DNtUY/1/

Comment: @ftom2 - JQuery solves cross browser problems at the expense of making everything much slower.  document.getElementById() is way faster than $() and works in all browers.

Comment: @SpaceBeers - Why not just do everything some other way than the way you're already doing it because other people have "better" ways of doing things? :-)

Comment: @evan - I think in this case it's a valid question. Specially when they way you're doing it doesn't work.

Comment: @SpaceBeers - In general, I agree, you should think about all possible answers. And in this case, there is a perfectly valid solution using all the information and technologies given.  CSS would require rewriting how the pages/images/rollovers already work.

Comment: @evan - Yeah a fair point. We're all here to learn stuff so I find it's good to see alternative approaches that might not have been considered (plus I find CSS easier than JS).

Comment: @evan Jquery does not make things "much slower" but maybe a little bit slower, for most things you won't even notice or care for the difference. Considering the benefits you get from using Jquery (or any other good js framework) , i think it is a very good option.

Comment: @ftom2 - Jquery makes things an order of magnitude slower (http://claudio.cicali.name/post/2010/01/jquery-vs-document-getelementbyid/).  As far as ultimate time, this may make something take .1 seconds instead of .01 seconds.  If you don't care about that performance loss, that's great for you.  If you work for a major website, it's extremely important and so much slower that it's not worth using in many cases.

Comment: @evan - this is an old article testing jquery 1.4 and states clearly that this is:  "simple and unreliable performance benchmark". As you know newer versions (1.7) have improved performance. Of course frameworks would usually be slower comparing to the real thing (after all it is running javascript under the hood), but it saves so much work and it usually does things much better and performant than  the average developer would do (like browser compatibility etc.).usually the time saved on maintenance and development is well worth it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code to this:

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>

        <img src="p1.png" name="img1"  onMouseOver="this.src='p2.png'" onMouseOut="this.src='p1.png'" />

    </body>
</html>
```

---

Also, I if your HTML page contains more data the the HTML page you've showed in your question, I suggest you put this code in the beginning of the `<body>` in order to preload the rollover image so there will be no delay when you want the rollover to work (otherwise, the rollover image will be downloaded to the user's device only when he hovers the image, causing a slight delay to the rollover (depending on the `onMouseOver` image size)):

```
<img src="p2.png" class="hiddenPic" />
<!-- loading (hidden) rollover image before all the other page data -->
```

And add the CSS `hiddenPic` class code: `.hiddenPic { display: none; }`

---

Other methods to preload the rollover image can be done using [CSS](https://www.google.co.il/search?hl=en&q=preload%20images%20css&oq=preload%20images%20css&gs_l=serp.3..0l2j0i30l8.2408.3542.0.3658.10.8.0.2.2.1.179.754.4j3.7.0...0.0...1c.82QAK4ScX-M) or the [JavaScript `onLoad` event handler](https://www.google.co.il/search?hl=en&q=javascript%20preload%20image%20onload&oq=javascript%20image%20onload&gs_l=serp.1.2.0i7j0j0i7j0j0i7j0l5.5963.6540.0.8020.2.2.0.0.0.0.151.290.0j2.2.0...0.0...1c.BHxz-zwmbGM).

Comment: You can load the other images using javascript at the bottom of the page after the page has already loaded.  No extraneous elements, no additional load time apparent to the user.

Comment: True, the hidden preloading is only effective if you want the rollover image to be ready as soon as possible, before everything else. Although it's usually not the issue, it can be useful sometimes, if the rollover has to be ready very quickly.

Answer (score 0):

```
onmouseover="this.src='p2.png'"
```

Use this instead of document.images....

Answer (score 0):

Another method (works if you need to rollover change something else as well):

```
<img src="p1.png" name="img3" id="img3" onMouseOver="document.getElementById('img3').src='p2.png'" onMouseOut="document.getElementById('img3').src='p1.png'" >
```

http://jsfiddle.net/DNtUY/5/  (3 examples, yours, Said's, this one).

PS. Your open tag is `<img ...>` but the close tag is `</a>`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe if the images are not that heavy, you might try a different approach like declaring both images and hide one of them. Then with javascript when you roll over the visible image, you hide it and show the other one.

Answer (score 0):

Perfectly working code for your question mr.Stighy:

```
<html> 
<head> 
  <style type="text/css">
</head> 
<body> 
 <img src="../a_b_c/a.jpg" alt="" onMouseOver="this.src='b.jpg'" onMouseOut="this.src='a.jpg'" onClick="this.src='c.jpg'" class="style1"></a>
</body> 
</html>
```

I think we messed up with the images, that's it... p.s. Giulio is waching you.